# Swift - JSON Serialisation of an nested object

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization

I have a object that is created from JSON (serialised). This object has an id property that represents another object stored in the system. How can I get the nested object during the serialisation?

```
import UIKit


class Person: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let addressId: String
    let address: Address // How to create it during serialisation

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName
        case lastName
        case addressId = "addressId"
    }

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, addressId:String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.addressId = addressId
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.firstName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        self.lastName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        self.addressId = try? values.decode(URL.self, forKey: .addressId)
    }
}

struct PersonsList : Codable {
    let persons: [Person]
}

class Address {

   static func getAddress(addressId: String) -> Address
   {
         //some code
         return address
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the original JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with lazy property

**EDIT**

Option1

```
 lazy var address:Address = { [unowned self] in
    return Address.getAddress(addressId: self.addressId)

  }()
```

Option 2

```
var  adreess1:Address {
    return Address.getAddress(addressId: self.addressId)
}
```

Comment: Will this be called automatically during the json serialisation?

Comment: @Luda With this you don't need to manually init Address object. when you access address property of `Person` it will be automatically initialised

Comment: I have this massage: 'lazy' must not be used on a computed property

Answer (score 0):

### JSON

Assuming this is your json

```
let json = """
[
    {
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Kirk",
        "address": { "id": "efg" }
    }
]
"""
```

### Model

You can simplify how you define your model

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let address: Address

    struct Address: Codable {
        let id: String
    }
}
```

> As you can see there is no need to write your custom `init(:from)`

### From JSON to Data

To test it not we are going to transform the json into a `Data` value.

```
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
```

### Decoding

And finally we can decode the data

```
if let persons = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: data) {
    print(persons.first?.address.id)
}
```

Output

```
Optional("efg")
```